# What is ohmic decay and why does it happen in magnetized celestial bodies like stars and pulsars?

Tags: astrophysics, plasma-physics, stars, neutron-stars, geomagnetism

I've seen term "ohmic decay" mentioned in several papers ([example](https://www.ias.ac.in/article/fulltext/joaa/038/03/0048)) regarding the decay of magnetic fields in celestial bodies like planets, stars, and pulsars, but I can't seem find a clear explanation to what it means and how it happens. By intuition, I figure that "ohmic decay" has something to do with reducing induced magnetic field by reducing current and changing resistivity (Lenz's & Ohm's law), but again I don't know why or what causes them to change.

Comment: The mentions in your linked paper are followed by references to a 1997 PhD thesis by Konar and a number of articles from that era with Konar as first author. It would be fruitful to follow those references.

Comment: Without having read anything, I imagine it is related to including the current density as $\mathbf J=\nabla\times\mathbf B$ in the MHD equations.

Comment: Hi Rob--I've tracked down these references (and more references therein), and both mention that ohmic decay in neutron stars has something to do with crustal currents being dissipated by the "finite electrical conductivity of the crustal lattice." I suppose there is a similar case in stars and planets where their fluid interiors have non-negligible resistivity, though I admit I'm not very confident in my interpretation based on my fairly limited knowledge of electromagnetism. I'm not sure if this answers my question, so I'd appreciate some input.

Comment: @arbodox - Yes, this would come out from a variation of Kyle's answer where you modify Ampere's and Faraday's laws to get a resistive dissipation term, e.g., $\partial B/\partial t \propto \eta \nabla^{2} B$ or something to that effect (where $\eta$ is the resistivity).